# C / C++ implement and pass code

Tags: c++, c

I have interpreter from another language in C. I have to pass code (about 200 lines) from another language to this interpreter and here problem occur.

```
char* command_line[] = {
    "", 
    "-e", 
    "print \"Hello from C!\\n\";"
};
```

This code is parse by:

```
(..)
    parser(my_p, NULL, 3, command_line, (char **)NULL);
(...)
```

In code abobe I use array but even simple code have to be wrapped with \ before chars like " ; | \ etc.

How to avoid this problem and pass more then 200 multi row lines of code comfortable?

Comment: As it stands, this is a terrible question. What does `parser` do? You can't tell anything from the question as it is.

Comment: It's not too bad! My understand is that he just wants to write code for the "interpreted language" in his C program, but having to escape all the special characters and quotes is tiresome.

Comment: load it from a file and do not put it into the source code.

Comment: is it c or c++? in c++(11) you have the option as in my above comment. in c, no such luck. but why not read from a file? also your question could really be better formulated, it's very hard to guess what is actually being asked (that that problem are the special characters)

Comment: @PeterWalser What did you change with respect to the [suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/2763712), why didn't you mark it as helpful and/or at least also remove the "thanks" at the end?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using C++11, you can use raw string literals.

```
R"(print "Hello from C!\n";)"
```

Or you can simply put all the data into an external file and just read it on start. No need to escape any data there.

Comment: Can you please provide example of load from external file ?

Comment: @DannyS http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/ and http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the C preprocessor to do the stringification for you:

```
#define STRINGIFY(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define STRINGIFY_NL(...) #__VA_ARGS__ "\n"

char* command_line[] = {
    "", 
    "-e", 
    STRINGIFY(print "Hello from C!\n";),    //< one element of the array

                                            //< another element of the array
                                            //< with embedded NL
    STRINGIFY_NL(print "Hello from C!")     //< no comma and the next line is glued
    STRINGIFY   ("for a second time";),     //< end of other string
};
```

The only restrictions to observe would be that possible `()` have to balance inside the argument to `STRINGIFY` and that you'd have to place the macro on each line that you want to escape.

Comment: It works but how to work with multi row text / code ?

Comment: If you enter several lines into this, they will be stashed together into one single line. I'll add something that would help you to add a nl character at the end of an input line.

Comment: This doesn't work if any of the lines contain a comma character.

Comment: @interjay, right, please see my edit. For this to work you'd need C99 or C++11, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no support for *literal strings* or similar useful constructs in C, so if you want to write the interpreted code inside your C program you will have to be careful and escape quotes and slashes as you have stated.

The alternative is to write the code into a text file and treat it as an external resource file. You can read the resource file from inside your code into a string and then pass that to `parser()`.

The ease of this depends on the platform you are using. Windows has good support for resource files and embedding them in to .exe files. I am sure it is possible with gcc too, but I haven't done it before.  A bit vague I'm afraid, but I hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a script to take your text input, as a file, and *stringify* it (escaping double-quotes and newlines):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

def main(argv = None):

    if argv is None:
        argv = sys.argv

    if len(argv) < 2:
        sys.stderr.write("Usage: stringify.py input.txt [... input.txt]\n")
        sys.exit(1)

    i = 1
    while i < len(argv):
        inname = argv[i]
        firstline = True
        try:
            infile = open(inname, "r")
            for line in infile:
                line = line.replace('"', '\\"').replace('\n', '\\n')
                sys.stdout.write('"{0}"\n'.format(line))
        except IOError, msg:
            sys.stderr.write("exception {0}\n".format(msg))
            return 2
        i = i + 1
    return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main())
```

Comment: <irony>Wow, that looks so universal :-D</irony>

Comment: @Let_Me_Be You don't like the idea of universal?

Comment: I don't see how this helps with the problem.

Comment: @MariusBancila Because it saves the OP from having to manually escape his input.